# Python list of lists with all combinations memoryerror

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to make a list with all the combinations of three other lists. xlijst2 has 355 items, ylijst2 has 35 items en zlijst2 has 420 items. This is my code:

```
alles = [xlijst2, ylijst2, zlijst2]
lijstje = list(itertools.product(*alles))
```

When I run it I get a MemoryError. Is there some sort of workaround?

Comment: I'm guessing you are literally running out of memory to store all of those combinations. Have you calculated the number of permutations you are expecting?

Comment: Yeah. Don't turn it into a list.

Comment: What are you trying to do, can you do it without making a list?

Comment: Did you mean to find all _permutations_ of those 3 lists? Use `itertools.permutations([a, b, c])` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the workaround is to use the `generator` that `itertools` returns, without casting it into an explicit list:

```
lijstje = itertools.product(*alles)
```

From there, you can iterate over the combinations one by one.

```
for elt in lijstje:
    ...do something()
```

Comment: This works too! And I think it is a little bit faster. Is that correct?

Comment: This and my answer boil down to the same thing - not casting the result of `itertools.product` to a list. My answer assumes you wished to view the results, in which case a file is the only sane way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There are **way** too many results for this to fit in ram. You will have to write it to a file. I should warn you though - this is not going to be a small number of items.

```
with open("values.txt", "w") as f:
    for value in itertools.product(*alles):
        f.write(", ".join(value) + "\n")
```

Comment: No problems :) For curiosities sake, how many lines ended up in that file?

Comment: It ended up with 5.218.500 lines (filesize is ~ 154 mb).